# Building a macro preprocessor using flex

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, preprocessor

I am just trying to write a flex code which will read a C file and write it another file after expanding the macros. My idea is to store the macro definitions declared at the beginning of the program in an array of (key,value) pair. So the regular expression for detecting the macro definitions can be (as of now, only consider #define statements):

```
%x DEFINE
%x DEFINE2
"#define" {BEGIN DEFINE};
<DEFINE>[a-zA-Z]+ {/* key = yytext*/}
<DEFINE>[ ] { BEGIN DEFINE2;/* begin the second state when a whitespace is encountered, it means the second part of the definition*/}
<DEFINE2>[a-zA-Z]+ { /* arr[key] = yytext; (storing the key value pair) */}
<DEFINE2> [ \t\n]+ {BEGIN INITIAL;}
```

The expressions are self explanatory. The main challenge that I am facing while expanding macros is detecting the occurrence of a macro key that we stored in these statements. How to handle macro statements of this kind?:

```
#define square(x) ((x)*(x))
...
int a,b = 4;
a = square(b);
```

The best way could be, adding new regular expression to the flex specification whenever a `#define` statement is encountered. But I don't think that is possible.
**So, is there any solution for expanding macros efficiently? How is it done in practice?**

Comment: Are you sure you need to handle function-like macros, and not just object-like ones?  Supporting function-like macros *greatly* complicates the problem.

Comment: More generally, how much of C preprocessor semantics do you actually need to implement?  For example, the standard preprocessor performs rescanning after it makes a substitution, so as to expand macros that appear in the substituted text, yet it excludes macro identifiers from which that text has directly or indirectly been expanded, so as to not enter infinite loops.  And then there's token pasting and stringification if indeed you do support function-like macros.

Comment: Also, of course, macro names can contain at least underscores and decimal digits in addition to letters, and macro replacement text can contain much more.

Comment: @JohnBollinger how will I handle just object kind of macros?

Comment: If you do not need to perform rescanning, then an approach along the lines you're currently attempting can work, but it would probably be more efficient to use a hash table rather than a flat array to store macro names and their definitions.  Then when you are not in macro-definition-scanning mode, you'll need to check each token against your table, whatever form that takes, to determine whether to output the token itself or some corresponding (and possibly empty) macro replacement text.

Comment: Phew.., if you are on the way to build a macro parser with lex, please refrain. Lex is really a nice *lexer* or *tokenizer*, but it is intended to be used with its companion syntactic parser which is `yacc` or `bison`. Read again tutorials on parsing with **both** lex and yacc. Here lex should only identify `#define` on start of line, `square` and `x` as identifiers, and parens and operators as what they are. Then the grammar should be handled by yacc or bison. There are 2 tools for the lexical and syntactic part for a reason.

Comment: If your intent is to write a C preprocessor (that is, a preprocessor which works as specified by the C language), you should take a look at [these GCC implementation notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html). But take account of the second paragraph! If you don't understand in detail how it is supposed to work, you are unlikely to write a correct implementation.